# Passing "(" and ")" through a URI causes a 403 error, how can I encode them?

Tags: javascript, xmlhttprequest, encode

(JavaScript for the XML HTTP request and PHP for the execution SQL query.)

I'm building a web app that executes queries. It uses the XMLHTTP request GET method and passes a query to a PHP script that executes it. It works fine until I introduce parentheses `( )` in it.

Here is an example of how works:

```
function executeQry(){
qry = document.getElementByID('textarea').value;
qryHTTPRequest(encodeURI(qry));
//I've also tried encodeURIComponent(qry);
}


function xmlHTTPRequest(qry){
//fetches 
urlFetch = "http://my.url.com/script.php?qry=" + qry;
 }
```

this is a quick reference, I know that my xmlhttp request works fine because it does what it needs to do when other queries are passed through for example:

```
SELECT * FROM `tableName`
```

works fine, but when you try to do something like

```
CREATE TABLE `new_table`
AS (SELECT * FROM `old_table`)
```

Then this is when it won't execute, I get the 403 error so I figured that it's an with the `()` because I even tried this same code on the PHP itself, without having to pass it through and it worked, so there must be an issue with the URL encoding process right? If this is the issue, is there a method for encoding these characters? I assume there are other characters that don't get encoded with `encodeURI()` method as well as the `encodeURIComponent()`. Thanks in advance!

Comment: This app seems ripe for hacking .. so be careful.. `(` and `)` are valid to be in the url and there should be no problem.. try without the **newline** and tell us if that is the problem.. Look at http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_403 for what 403 error is..

Comment: Passing SQL queries between the client and server is a really bad idea. It allows for arbitrary SQL injection. Anyone can trash your database.

Comment: Are you really sure that its the parentheses?  Have you tried this with a very basic PHP page?  E.g. `<?= $_GET['qry'] ?>`  If that fails, I think your hosting provider may be screening out dangerous looking queries.  Otherwise, it could be that your script doesn't have access to create tables and your library is throwing the 403.  You could also try an insert statement to see if that gets an error.

Comment: Brian, It works with other queries, but when I introduce a query with `(` and `)` the xml response returns a 403 error. I think you guys are right but how is it that phpMyAdmin is allowed to run these queries dynamically without encountering this issue? I use the same user name and password to access the databases.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The below should do it:

```
urlFetch = "http://my.url.com/script.php?qry=" + encodeURIComponent(qry)
    .replace(/\(/g, "%28").replace(/\)/g, "%29");
```

Parentheses are oddballs in the URI grammar.  Many encoders treat them as special even though they *only* appear in the *obsolete* "mark" production.  With common web protocols (`http`, `https`, `mailto`) it is safe to encode them to `%28` and `%29` though web servers are allowed to assign special meanings to them.  You are already using `encodeURI` or `encodeURIComponent` so you are already assuming that URL escape sequences are UTF-8.

From RFC 3986:

> ```
> sub-delims    "!" / "$" / "&" / "'" / "(" / ")"
>             / "*" / "+" / "," / ";" / "="
> ```
>
> ...
>
> ```
> obsolete rule     translation
> mark              "-" / "_" / "." / "!" / "~" / "*" / "'"
>                 / "(" / ")"
> ```

Comment: @ArchitGarg, I'm unaware of this `encode()` method.  Do you have a documentation link?

Answer (score 2):

As the commenters you have a number of issues.  Brackets () and [] are valid in URIs but have specific purposes hence they are not encoded by standard encode functions.

Secondly, it is a really bad idea to send SQL over the wire, especially in a get request.  See [RFC 2616](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2616#page-51).  Methods like get and head are considered 'safe', they should only implement retrieval, they are not meant to change state.  I would really reconsider what you are doing and see if you could achieve it in a cleaner way, possibly seeking opinions on your conceptual architecture at [Programmers.stackexchange](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: +1 for SQL query caveat.   I didn't even think query might be SQL.

Comment: It works on the phpMyAdmin app, so I don't think the server is filtering out the bad code. If this is the case, how can the phpMyAdmin app run queries and bypass this issue?