# Server giving 403 error on ajax submit

Tags: javascript, php, html, codeigniter, http

I am working on a new project like jsfiddle.
I am facing a problem while development of it. When I try to send a ajax request with JS `alert()` function in text box the server is giving a 403 error. Can anyone help me with this?

Example:
Go to this URL: http://www.labs.codeteam.in/lab

Enter `alert(1)` in javascript textbox and Run the project, the server will give a 403 error in console.

Comment: I would check my htaccess - maybe for url /runProject you have set deny from all or smth? Or maybe your posts are CSRF protected, and you don't send CSRF token?

Comment: Can you post your controllers code?

Comment: I don't think it is because of the controller code. Because if I keep the controller code empty it gives me the same error.

Comment: But when I run the code on my local machine its working properly.

Comment: Do you get 403 even if you send ajax by GET method, and not POST?

Comment: I know, but did you try to use GET for this?

Comment: Its giving error in both GET & POST

Comment: Well, I can see that this is not true :) - when I went to http://www.labs.codeteam.in/lab/runProject in my browser everything went ok, so the problem probably is that you're CSRF protected (are you?), or something's wrong with your data - maybe sending `alert(`)` is being considered by the server as attack attempt?

Comment: I am using Chrome, which browser are you using?

Comment: Mozilla Firefox. I opened this url http://www.labs.codeteam.in/lab/runProject in Chrome, and everything went ok... Maybe you IP is blocked by the server?

Comment: Its not working at my end. Any suggestion to this problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*A web server may return a 403 Forbidden HTTP status code in response to a request from a client for a web page or resource to indicate that **the server can be reached and understood the request**, but refuses to take any further action.
Status code 403 responses are the result of **the web server being configured to deny access, for some reason**, to the requested resource by the client.*

The server might be configure to prevent script injection. Sending "alert()" with your post to the server might look like some type of injection attempt to the server.

Comment: So what is the solution?

Answer (score 2):

try urlEncode your string before sending it back to your controller and then u can decode it back in php when u get it

It's actually encodeURI http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_encodeURI.asp

Comment: I don't think that urlencode will encode keywords like alert which is causing problem.

Comment: the brackets is causing the problem not alert keyword

Comment: i just wrote alert and hit run and it did not break the code, php doesn't know alert is a keyword in javascript

Comment: But which function to use in js to encode. encodeURI is not encoding the brackets

Comment: refer to this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8143085/passing-and-through-a-uri-causes-a-403-error-how-can-i-encode-them

Answer (score 0):

I have found a different way to do this.
While submitting the data in ajax request I will reverse the string so that the server cannot recognize the keywords and in php I'll reverse it back and use it.

Answer (score 0):

Did you find the solution to your problem?
I happen to have the same problem, I thought my server was slowing down for some reason, but after making a ping -i .1 domain.com, from 2000 packets sent, only .1%~ was packet loss. My queries are about 2ms.

I jumped in the conclusion that it might be that the requests are too many for the server to handle at the same time (I'm doing periodical ajax request [about 1 every 4 seconds], in 2 js scripts).

Answer (score -1):

The error is in your data - try sending something useless like "asdfasdfasdfas" - it will be okay, at least I pasted that in the text box, hit run, and on the url http://www.labs.codeteam.in/lab/runProject I got 200 status code. When I wrote `alert(1)`, then indeed 403 status code was thrown - your server is treating javascript data as an attempt to inject code.

Comment: Is there a way to stop this by htaccess or by setting header etc.?

Comment: No - it's your PHP code, thats making it work like that.

Comment: I tried that as well but same result. And I don't think its Php issue becasues it is working on my local system.

Comment: Ok, so you should do something about your server side data validation. I can't help you more that saying this :)